# How to pass multiple parameters in thread in VB

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio

I'm looking to pass two or more parameters to a thread in VB 2008.

The following method (modified) works fine without parameters, and my status bar gets updated very cool-y.
But I can't seem to make it work with one, two or more parameters.

This is the pseudo code of what I'm thinking should happen when the button is pressed:

```
Private Sub Btn_Click() 

Dim evaluator As New Thread(AddressOf Me.testthread(goodList, 1))
evaluator.Start()

Exit Sub
```

This is the testthread method:

```
Private Sub testthread(ByRef goodList As List(Of OneItem), ByVal coolvalue As Integer)

    StatusProgressBar.Maximum = 100000
    While (coolvalue < 100000)
        coolvalue = coolvalue + 1
        StatusProgressBar.Value = coolvalue
        lblPercent.Text = coolvalue & "%"
        Me.StatusProgressBar.Refresh()
    End While

End Sub
```

Answer (score 44):

**First of all**: `AddressOf` just gets the delegate to a function - you cannot specify anything else (i.e. capture any variables).

Now, you can start up a thread in two possible ways.

- Pass an `Action` in the constructor and just `Start()` the thread.
- Pass a `ParameterizedThreadStart` and forward *one* extra object argument to the method pointed to when calling `.Start(parameter)`

I consider the latter option an anachronism from pre-generic, pre-lambda times - which have ended at the latest with VB10.

You *could* use that crude method and create a list or structure which you pass to your threading code as this *single object parameter*, but since we **now** have closures, you can just create the thread on an anonymous `Sub` that knows all necessary variables by itself (which is work performed for you by the compiler).

Soo ...

```
Dim Evaluator = New Thread(Sub() Me.TestThread(goodList, 1))
```

It's really just that ;)

Comment: @elcool: I don't think this requires .Net 4.0 or VS 2010. This looks like .Net 3.5 to me.

Comment: @dboarman: It is VB2010 ... The 3.5-Version is limited to `Function(...)`-Lambdas but unable to handle `Sub`s

Comment: ah, the `Sub()` -- missed that part. I'm still doing VB/C# 3.5 at work and only C# 4.0 at home.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this (I'm not a VB programmer)

```
Public Class MyParameters
    public Name As String
    public Number As Integer
End Class



newThread as thread = new Thread( AddressOf DoWork)
Dim parameters As New MyParameters
parameters.Name = "Arne"
newThread.Start(parameters);

public shared sub DoWork(byval data as object)
{
    dim parameters = CType(data, Parameters)

}
```

Comment: dude this is not even vb

Comment: It's pseudo code, but the concept is still the same. It's how you do it in .NET.

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim evaluator As New Thread(Sub() Me.testthread(goodList, 1))
With evaluator
.IsBackground = True ' not necessary...
.Start()
End With
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, the straightforward method is to create an appropriate class/structure which holds all your parameter values and pass that to the thread.

Another solution in VB10 is to use the fact that lambdas create a *closure*, which basically means the compiler doing the above automatically for you:

```
Dim evaluator As New Thread(Sub()
                                testthread(goodList, 1)
                            End Sub)
```

Comment: I read about this lambdas, but I'm using VS 2008 with VB8 I believe. Don't have VB10

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Dario stated about the Delegates you could execute a delegate with several parameters:

Predefine your delegate:

```
Private Delegate Sub TestThreadDelegate(ByRef goodList As List(Of String), ByVal coolvalue As Integer)
```

Get a handle to the delegate, create parameters in an array, DynamicInvoke on the Delegate:

```
Dim tester As TestThreadDelegate = AddressOf Me.testthread
Dim params(1) As Object
params(0) = New List(Of String)
params(1) = 0

tester.DynamicInvoke(params)
```

Comment: DynamicInvoke ... goodbye type safety. A valid answer nontheless.

Comment: @Jay I'm curious to know whether or not it is necessary to 'build up' the parameters in an Object as you are doing in your example.  When I implement your solution it works however if I simply include the parameters without building them up I get no errors and the behavior is the same as when I build up the param object.  Also I'm using BeginInvoke rather than DynamicInvoke. Not sure if this would make a difference.   `BeginInvoke(dlg, params)`.  Again when I include the parameters as in `BeginInvoke(dlg, strParam, intParam)` it works just the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a class or structure that has two members, one `List(Of OneItem)` and the other `Integer` and send in an instance of that class.

Edit: Sorry, missed that you had problems with one parameter as well. Just look at [Thread Constructor (ParameterizedThreadStart)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h2f2459.aspx) and that page includes a simple sample.

Comment: Yes, it worked with one parameter using ParameterizedThreadStart. But I want to use the same solution for one or two or more paramenters

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you... 
**[Creating Threads and Passing Data at Start Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts553s52(v=vs.110).aspx)**!

```
Imports System.Threading

' The ThreadWithState class contains the information needed for 
' a task, and the method that executes the task. 
Public Class ThreadWithState
    ' State information used in the task. 
    Private boilerplate As String 
    Private value As Integer 

    ' The constructor obtains the state information. 
    Public Sub New(text As String, number As Integer)
        boilerplate = text
        value = number
    End Sub 

    ' The thread procedure performs the task, such as formatting 
    ' and printing a document. 
    Public Sub ThreadProc()
        Console.WriteLine(boilerplate, value)
    End Sub  
End Class 

' Entry point for the example. 
' 
Public Class Example
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        ' Supply the state information required by the task. 
        Dim tws As New ThreadWithState( _
            "This report displays the number {0}.", 42)

        ' Create a thread to execute the task, and then 
        ' start the thread. 
        Dim t As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf tws.ThreadProc))
        t.Start()
        Console.WriteLine("Main thread does some work, then waits.")
        t.Join()
        Console.WriteLine( _
            "Independent task has completed main thread ends.")
    End Sub 
End Class 
' The example displays the following output: 
'       Main thread does some work, then waits. 
'       This report displays the number 42. 
'       Independent task has completed; main thread ends.
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass multiple parameter for VB.NET 3.5

```
 Public Class MyWork

    Public Structure thread_Data            
        Dim TCPIPAddr As String
        Dim TCPIPPort As Integer            
    End Structure

    Dim STthread_Data As thread_Data
    STthread_Data.TCPIPAddr = "192.168.2.2"
    STthread_Data.TCPIPPort = 80  

    Dim multiThread As Thread = New Thread(AddressOf testthread)
    multiThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA)
    multiThread.Start(STthread_Data)     

    Private Function testthread(ByVal STthread_Data As thread_Data) 
        Dim IPaddr as string = STthread_Data.TCPIPAddr
        Dim IPport as integer = STthread_Data.TCPIPPort
        'Your work'        
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

With VB 14, you can do the following with Tuples:

```vb
Shared Sub _runner(data as (goodList As List(Of OneItem), coolvalue As Integer))
    Console.WriteLine($"goodList: {data.goodList}")
    Console.WriteLine($"coolvalue: {data.coolvalue}")
    ' do stuff...
End Sub
Dim thr As New Thread(AddressOf _runner)
thr.Start((myGoodList, cval))
```