# VB.Net Multi-Threading InvokeRequired and Passing Thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, invoke

I need to be able to pass the thread name into a subroutine in order to abort it when I need to.

So I have this so far:

```
 Dim BrowserSpawn As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf BrowserSub)
    BrowserSpawn.Start()

 Private Async Sub BrowserSub(BrowserSpawn)
...
End Sub
```

Because the subroutine creates a browser within Form1 groups I needed to invoke access to these controls within the sub.

**Note: This works fine when I'm not passing in the thread name.**

```
 If Me.GroupNamehere.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.GroupNamehere.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf BrowserSub))
        Else
           'Do nothing
        End If
```

When I'm passing in the thread name these become a problem when trying to compile:

```
Method does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub MethodInvoker()'.
```

I'm hoping this is just a syntax thing but I can't seem to get it to work. Is there any way I'm able to pass in this thread name without breaking my invokerequired check?

If I try and change it to the obvious:

```
Me.GroupNamehere.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf BrowserSub(BrowserSpawn)))
```

It tells me Addressof operand must be the name of a method (without parentheses). Although without the parentheses it's not happy either so I don't know where to go from here.

/edit:

Stumbled across [How can I create a new thread AddressOf a function with parameters in VB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30162382/how-can-i-create-a-new-thread-addressof-a-function-with-parameters-in-vb)

Which seems to confirm what I was trying passing something like:

```
Private Sub test2(Threadname As Thread)
    ' Do something
End Sub
```

And the sub seems happy with that. But I'm not sure how to do that without breaking the invoker part.

```
 Me.GroupNameHere.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf SubNameHere))
```

Works normally. If SubNameHere() becomes SubNameHere(threadname as thread) then that seems happy enough but the invoke line breaks and doesn't want more than the address of.

Comment: When defining a Sub the part in the `()` is for defining the parameters not passing an object. `Public Sub Foo(fubar As String)`

Comment: Unless I'm missing something MSDN says you can pass objects as well? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxa9y69d(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Not in the declaration! You pass objects to it when you call it. `Foo("something")`

Comment: I've tried calling the thread and passing in the thread name like  BrowserSpawn.Start(BrowserSpawn) but if the sub is just BrowserSub() then it's not using it. If it's BrowserSub(BrowserSpawn) it seems to be fine using the thread but it breaks the invoker code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two slight syntax changes sorted it:

```
Private Async Sub SubName(ThreadNameAs Thread)
```

and

```
GroupName.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() Me.SubName(ThreadName)))
```