# How to put received serial text into multiple text boxes?

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, serial-communication, rs485

I am doing a serial communication project and would like to have the received string go into a text box based on which button was clicked to send the initial string and invoke a response.

The code for the ReceivedText is:

```
PrivateSub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String)

   Button1.Clear()
   Button2.Clear()

   If Button1.InvokeRequired Then
       RichTextBox1.text = [text].Trim("!")
   End If

   If Button2.InvokeRequired Then
       RichTextBox2.Text = [text].Trim("!")
   End If

EndSub
```

This just results in the received string going into *both* of the boxes instead of one or the other.

Is there any way to get the text to go in the appropriate box?

Comment: What is your Clear method supposed to do? That's not a member of a standard button type. Nevertheless, if you can't distinguish from the response text which button was pushed, then I see at least a couple options. Simplest is public variable that holds which button was clicked.

Comment: However, that won't work if you can press both buttons at once or before a response is read from prior command. If that's a requirement, then you would start a thread for each button press and pass in a class that contained the button name and command like the accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30162382/how-can-i-create-a-new-thread-addressof-a-function-with-parameters-in-vb so you could read back the name when it finished.

Comment: @topshot I corrected the Clear method and placed it in the appropriate line. I am very new to this and am not familiar with threading, is there an example you can provide? I would imagine it's fairly simple to have a received string go in a certain place based on which button was clicked...

Comment: See the link in my second comment above for how someone passed parameters to a thread. As for threading tutorials, MSDN docs or look for some of the threading posts in the VB.Net **CodeBank** section of VBForums.com (specifically those by jmcilhinney or Niya)

Comment: @topshot aside from the Clear function, what is preventing the text from going into the correct box? I don't understand what part of that code would call for the text to go in both boxes

Comment: @topshot figured it out. Now if I want to have the text in the box display something based on the incoming string but _not actually be the string_, how would I do that? For example, if the existing data reads "!+0007." and I want the textbox to read "Type K", how can I make that happen?

Comment: Any number of ways depending on how varied the data is and number of possible "Type ?". If small number, `If ...Then ... Elseif ... Elseif ... Else ... End If` could work. `Select Case` could work. Large number I'd probably make a lookup table, which could be a DataTable, Array, List, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The key to remember is that .Net treats all serial comm as threads. Let me give you a simple example of updating textboxes from one of my programs that reads data from a scale.

```
Private Sub ComScale_DataReceived(sender As System.Object, e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles ComScale.DataReceived

    If ComScale.IsOpen Then
        Try
            ' read entire string until .Newline 
            readScaleBuffer = ComScale.ReadLine()

            'data to UI thread because you can't update the GUI here
            Me.BeginInvoke(New EventHandler(AddressOf DoScaleUpdate))

        Catch ex As Exception : err(ex.ToString)

        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

You'll note a routine DoScaleUpdate is invoked which does the GUI stuff:

```
Public Sub DoScaleUpdate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Try
        'getAveryWgt just parses what was read into something like this {"20.90", "LB", "GROSS"}
        Dim rst() As String = getAveryWgt(readScaleBuffer)
        txtWgt.Text = rst(0)
        txtUom.Text = rst(1)
        txttype.Text = rst(2)
    Catch ex As Exception : err(ex.ToString)

    End Try
End Sub
```

You CAN make it much more complicated if you choose (see post #15 of [this thread](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?761597-RESOLVED-VB-2010-Express-Serial-port-threading-problem) for an example) but this should be enough to do what you need.