# vb.net threads not starting

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I've written a small web spider to check an internal website is returning search results correctly (around once a day it doesn't for various reasons). It runs find in serial, but takes a long time, so I was hoping to split some parts of it into independent threads.

The code below never seems to launch the function "ripitems" which would leave a file for me to read into excel later.

```
Sub doSearch()
   Dim myVar As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of IWebElement)

   Dim csvFile As String, myContinue As Boolean
   Dim objWriter As TextWriter
   Dim myDriver As New Chrome.ChromeDriver

   csvFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments _
            & "\Catalogue Download - " & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd") & ".csv"
   objWriter = TextWriter.Synchronized(File.AppendText(csvFile))

   For i = 2 To 10
        myDriver.Navigate.GoToUrl("mysite/search?QueryExpr=" & searchFor & "&pid=" & i)
        myVar = myDriver.FindElementsByClassName("upperContainer")
        Dim myThread As New Thread(Sub() ripitems(myVar, objWriter))
        myThread.Start()
   Next
End Sub


Function ripitems(ByVal elementCollection As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of IWebElement), ByVal fHandle As TextWriter)
    [... irrelevant code to find items and prices ...]
    For i = 0 To elementCollection.Count - 1
        fHandle.Write(thisPN(i) & "," & thisPrice(i))
    Next
End Function
```

I've pulled most of threading code from [this SE answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4018354/317958), 
What have I done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Have you placed breakpoints to verify that the code is executed as it should?

Comment: The whole of the main sub runs fine, no errors, and the search moves up in number. Stepping through, the cursor goes to the `myThread.Start()` line, does something for a fraction of a second when you hit F11 and then carries on... the Function code is never run as far as I can tell in debug, and if I put a breakpoint in the function the IDE tells me _This breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the debuggers target code is associated with this line_

Comment: I think `Function ripitems` should be `Sub ripitems`. You're not actually returning anything (turning **Option Strict On** would show this) so `Sub` should be fine.

Comment: That's done it! if you add that as an answer, I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method should not be a `Function`:

```
Function ripitems(ByVal elementCollection As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of IWebElement), ByVal fHandle As TextWriter)
    '[... irrelevant code to find items and prices ...]
    For i = 0 To elementCollection.Count - 1
        fHandle.Write(thisPN(i) & "," & thisPrice(i))
    Next
End Function
```

Instead replace `Function` with `Sub`:

```
Sub ripitems(ByVal elementCollection As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of IWebElement), ByVal fHandle As TextWriter)
    '[... irrelevant code to find items and prices ...]
    For i = 0 To elementCollection.Count - 1
        fHandle.Write(thisPN(i) & "," & thisPrice(i))
    Next
End Sub
```